# Firmware settings

Tags: macos, startup, firmware

I want to open the firmware settings.
I have a Mac book Pro end 2011 and yosemite.

When i press Option+Cmd+O+F while booting nothing happens, it continues to boot.

What do i have to do?

Background:

i want to install ubuntu but i get black screen.
Here is writen that you have to change something in the settings.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

In section "3. Black screen" it is written:

The picture above actually only confirms DVD/USB booted using UEFI and there will be some means in firmware settings to ensure drives are booted in order to make UEFI installer run - the solution to which may possibly be as simple as ensuring SATA set to AHCI - check your vendors manual to check this. Also check UEFI Community Documentation Section 2.3 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Open Firmware's life in the Apple universe ended with the last PPC-Mac. Intel-Mac (as your MacBook Pro end 2011) use EFI.

Choose [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) (no longer maintained) or better [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) instead.

Please check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272715/ubuntu-12-04-does-not-start-on-macbook-pro-black-screen) and the answers at askubuntu.

Comment: i made an edit i need to change some settings

Comment: @user3613886 i made some edits too